# Apply the complex exponential function to a region of the plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Considering the complex exponential map $w=e^{z}$, I want to see what the image of the function would look like for the following region of the complex plane

$$\text{The disk} \quad |z| \leq \pi$$

Note that the region is represented graphically as follows

[image: region]

Initially the points (in the axis $x$) of the disk are described by $- \pi \leq x \leq \pi$, similarly $- \pi \leq y \leq \pi$ so, if I apply the function we have that:

$$e^{- \pi} \leq e^{x} \leq e^{ \pi}$$

I understand that the modules will now be placed between $e^{- \pi}$ and $e^{ \pi}$ that is, they will only take positive values. So you could say that by sending such a disk through the function, you almost translate the ball on the $x$-axis, something like the following would I think

[image: plane]

I really don't see clearly what the result is, any suggestions or help? I would appreciate it!

Comment: Note $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful to thing about what happens on "vertical lines" (lines of constant $\Re z$).  These get sent to circles of radius $\Re z$ and the imaginary part tells you which angles on that circle are part of your image.  When $\Re(z) = -\pi$, the one point at angle $0$ of the circle of radius $\mathrm{e}^{-\pi}$ is part of the image.  Since the vertical range the domain generally does not include an entire $2\pi$ segment in the vertical direction, the image only lands on arcs of the circles, leaving a "hole" in the image near the negative real axis until ... When $\Re(z) = 0$, the angle ranges from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, so that entire circle is present.  Then as the real part continues to increase, the radii of the circles increases to $\mathrm{e}^{\pi}$, but the range of angles decreases until when $\Re z = \pi$, only the point where that circle meets the positive real axis is in the image.

Zoomed in to see the hole left by the short range of angles from the left half of the domain circle:

[image]

Zoomed out to see the whole image:

[image]

The circles, centered at the origin, in these images are images of lines of constant real part in the domain.  The rays (starting near the origin and pointing radially outward) are images of lines of constant imaginary part in the domain.